# How to create a consistent style across stock images for a website?

Tags: website-design, images, style, stock-images, consistency

I am currently applying changes to [this site](http://fbhinstitute.com).

Becky, my customer, demands that the **images be changed** so that
the image content will also be **compatible with each other**.

I tried using icons and vector art, etc, but they rejected all of the ones I offered.

[image]

I tried changing the imagery with each version by changing the style of the images, but I don't know how to do it. I thought maybe a color overlay layer is helpful. Something like this:

[image]

<sub>The first image is taken from smashing magazine .com and the second is from devpedia.ir</sub>

Essentially creating a color overlay layer with text overlaid on top.

They rejected this idea.

Then I thought maybe create a different shape from images with same style? Something like this:

[image]

But they rejected this idea as well. I've tried many ideas and many ways but the customer rejects them all.

**Are there any other ways to create consistency between a group of differing images?**

Comment: The only question I see here is in the title, but it's pretty open ended... The description only serves to confuse me. I have no idea what it is that you want.

Comment: Hi Developers Pedia, your questions seems to be more geared towards brain storming which is considered off topic. Can you rephrase your question to be more specific?

Comment: Sounds like you just have a pain in the ass customer. That happens sometimes. Sometimes you have to let those ones go.

Comment: @joonas I need an idea to challenge with my customer...

Comment: @AndrewH yes absolutely

Comment: @DA01 They want me to have a complete design.
but do not know what it wants.
I am looking for a good idea

Comment: Clients like that may not respond to 'good ideas'. They think they have an idea in their head, but it's usually not all that profound. They know what they don't like, but not what they do like. This sounds like a client management problem more than a design problem. I'd suggest asking them for examples. ask them what web sites they feel does what they are looking for well. Get them to actually visualize what they want for you.

Comment: @DA01 I ask them thousand times and every time they said, "I don't have an idea, do it yourself".

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd say these are definitely clients you don't want. If you have the ability to fire them, I suggest you do. If not, I don't know what you can do but be sure to charge them for every hour of work you are doing on this. At a certain point, you have to let the budget make the decisions.

Comment: To reiterate what @DA01 had to say: I had a client like this once. I kept charging for their indecision and scope changes. I made a good deal of money before finally being told they would be handling things in-house from now on for "cost reasons". Just be sure to get paid as you go -- don't give them one big bill at the end!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Colours

- Tune the clarity, vibrancy, and saturation to a similar level across the entire collection of images as much as possible by eye

  Your images look a bit washed out/desaturated to me, but this isn't a critique. Just try to make them each share similar levels of vibrancy, saturation, and clarity.
- I tend to mask out the original skies in collections of poor outdoor photos and replace them with a consistent, sunny, (happy) sky
- Sometimes during the photo-finding phase it can be good to add an additional constraint of looking for photos with colours consistent to your colour scheme *or* finding images where changing the colours to fit your scheme won't be too difficult

#### Perspective

- Finding photos with a similar general "plane"/perspective really helps to create consistency

  For example, many of your images are, for want of a better term, "eye-level". That makes the birds eye view image very inconsistent. Either find a common perspective, or make sure that the perspective differs enough across the entire collection (don't have 95% eye-level, 5% birds eye view -- try to mix it up a bit more).

#### Level of Detail

- Use images with a consistent level of detail

  For example, most of your images are photographic, which just doesn't have any consistency with the simple, "non-realistic" graphics. Stick with either simple graphics or photo graphics, but not both for the same purpose.

#### Framing / Background

- Ensure the images essentially *look* like they were made specifically for their frame

  For example, the image of two couples with a broken heart is encased within another frame, which just makes it look like it was pasted in amateurishly.
- Use images with similar background *compositions*

  This doesn't mean all nature backgrounds, or all purple backgrounds, it means don't have some full background images, and some "light-boxed", (with a lot of literal white space).

Comment: First, thank you for the changes in question.
Next, these photos selected by customer/employer and I just have to change styles.

Comment: @DevelopersPedia If I were in your position I think I'd first tune the colours across all of the images and fix the frame on that broken heart (maybe even change the background colour to fit the colour scheme better). Then explain to the client based on some of the points above, that they need to reselect two of the images, (the 3D one and the birds eye view one), if they want it to look as good as possible. If they refuse I'd just fix what I could and tell them I didn't take/choose the photos, so I can't be responsible for their effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

I can not really help you with your customer demands – and I fear hardly anybody can.

Maybe you're actually not involved with the building of the actual website – and you are 'just' building sample layouts? But still I would like to recommend that you don't change the actual images that are uploaded to the website – but instead change *the appearance* of the images by applying **CSS3 styles**.

All of the examples you've given could be achieved throug the use of CSS. The actual effect would render in the browser while the images stay the same. That would make using css styles more flexible than actually manipulating the images. You can basically change all image styles at once and don't have to re-render and re-upload any of the images. So even if your client later decides to just have another style applied, you can do that without much stress.

And even if you are not actually building the website, looking at what **can** be done with pure css might also help you get some new fresh ideas – and at the same time you're on the safe side when it comes to the actual website construction. [Here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-image-styles) is a page with some examples from 2011 – but you'll probably find a lot more when you're searching for "css3 image styles" or the like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.

I will try that and announce the result.